# How can I get my Facebook posts translated from English to another language?

Tags: facebook

How can I have integrated translation of Facebook posts from English to another language in my browser? I have seen that in some cases, Facebook adds a "Translate" link, but not in my non-English account.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook auto-translates comments in some circumstances, see http://www.geek.com/articles/news/facebook-starts-experimenting-with-comment-translations-2011095/ . What language are you hoping to translate to?

The other option is to use a browser plugin such as Google Translate for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en . Most browsers have plugins that include extensions to quickly highlight text and translate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Babylon translation](http://translation.babylon.com). It allows you to translate quickly from many different languages and to post. It also has an app for your phone so you can it do while you’re mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides various language and language translation settings, one of which may do what you required. To access them, open Facebook's settings by clicking the downwards pointing triangle to the right of the top nagivation bar, then click "**Settings**" then click the "**Language**" tab.

[image: Screenshot shows Facebook's language and language translation settings]